# Вопрос относительно GoogleAd отрисовки и размеров

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-adsense

**Проблема в том, что** - можно ли как то сделать запрос на получение Ad размером `728*90` и установить его во вью размером `600*90`?

Получается, что в портретном режиме Ad получается обрезанным, но в landscape режиме все выглядит хорошо.

Portrait:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Landscape:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую для тестов планшет и загружать Ad пробую в `AdManagerAdView`.

Я обнаружил, что проблема в том, что я пробую загрузить Ad размером `728*90` в то время как ширина планшета в портрете `600dp` так что понятно, почему `128dp` не помещается на экране.

Согласно всем возможным конфигурациям (https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/banner#banner_sizes) я проверил их все

```
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(320, 50)) +
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(320, 100))
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(300, 250)) +
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(468, 60))
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(728, 90)) +
```

и получилось, что работают только те что отмечены `+`

```
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(320, 50)) +
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(300, 250)) +
            this.setAdSizes(AdSize(728, 90)) +
```

Выходит, что если мне нужно взять следующее по значению (в меньшую сторону) размер то это будет `300*250` что совершенно отличается от того, что мне нужно `600*90`

Я нашел, что можно использовать так же `NativeAd` (https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/native/start), но тогода я получаю ошибку:

```
onAdFailedToLoad: {
                   "Code": 3,
                   "Message": "No ad config.",
                   "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
                   "Cause": "null",
                   "Response Info": {
                     "Response ID": "null",
                     "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
                     "Adapter Responses": []
                   }
                 }
```

Я так понимаю, что для того, чтоб начать использовать такой тип Ad нужно, чтоб оно сначала поддерживалось на стороне паблишера (так как я понял).

В итоге вопрос - можно ли как то сделать запрос на получение Ad размером `728*90` и установить его во вью размером `600*90`?

Comment: Smart Banner не подойдет? Он сам подгонит размер под имеющееся пространство

Comment: @Style-7 не совсем так, во первый он уже устаревший (используется AdaptiveBanners - https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/banner/anchored-adaptive) а во вторых (я так понял), что он только находит нужный размер который максимально подходит для определенного экрана, но сам банер он берет из доступного перечня, в моем случае это будет `300*250`

Comment: вариант с уменьшением scale of ad view не пробовали?

Comment: @Style-7 дело в том, что adView внутри себя создает дополнительные view которые нельзя контролировать, то есть даже если я делаю ad view меньше то ad image все равно обрезается так как она держится того размера который был запрошен (728)

Comment: Есть вариант поместить AdView в какой-нибудь контейнер (ViewGroop) и масштабировать его, все "дети" масштабируются автоматически.

Comment: @Style-7 не совсем так, вот на первом скриншоте видно какой результат получается, хотя `AdView` является child для `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделать это так как я хотел не получилось и я сделал так, показываю то обьявление которое подходит по ширине. Если ширина экрана больше чем 728 то большой банер, если ширина меньше но больше чем 300 то значит такой банер. Я думаю код здесь показывать не нужно, все достаточно просто.